# How to zip each element from a 1D array with the elements from each row of a 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, list-comprehension

I am trying to plot a dataset using `matplotlib` which contains multiple `y` coordinates per `x`. To plot them I have to combine these arrays to show them in a single plot. How do I zip each element from a 1D array with the elements from each row of a 2D array (corresponding with the index for the element of the 1D array)? Without using explicit for-loops. Using built-ins (eg. zip/list comprehension) or even better: `numpy`?

**Turning:**

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

**Into:**

```
r = [(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of following:

1. Extend `x` to be of same size as `y`
2. Flatten `y`
3. Zip `x` and `y`

as follows

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]
>>> x = np.array(x).repeat(2)
>>> y = np.array(y).reshape(-1)
>>> list(zip(x, y))
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9)]
```

I would love to learn how more efficiently this can be done.

Please comment or answer more efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]

result = [(i[0], i[1][0]) for i in zip(x,y)] + [(i[0], i[1][1]) for i in zip(x,y)]
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 8), (1, 5), (2, 7), (3, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by approach 5 [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-merge-two-lists-into-list-of-tuples/):

```
from functools import reduce

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]

def listOfTuples(l1, l2): 
    l = list(map(lambda x, y:[(x,y[0]), (x,y[1])], l1, l2))
    m = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l)
    return(m)

r = listOfTuples(x, y)
```

Gives

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on your `repeat` and `reshape` approach:

```
In [89]: x = [1, 2, 3] 
    ...: y = [[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]                                                          
In [90]: res = np.zeros((3,2,2),int)                                                           
In [91]: res[:,:,1]=y                                                                          
In [92]: res[:,:,0]=np.array(x)[:,None]                                                        
In [93]: res                                                                                   
Out[93]: 
array([[[1, 4],
        [1, 5]],

       [[2, 6],
        [2, 7]],

       [[3, 8],
        [3, 9]]])
In [94]: res.reshape(6,2)                                                                      
Out[94]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 8],
       [3, 9]])
```

It's using `broadcasting` to map the `x` and `y` onto the `res` array.

Answer (score 0):

This is making use of iterators only, using 
`itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
import itertools

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [[4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]

list(zip(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(n, 2) for n in x)),
     list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(y))))
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9)]
```

This should be faster in longer runs, IMHO.